# C++ constructor initializer list throw exceptions

Tags: c++, list, exception, constructor, initializer

I have a problem with the following code. As we can see I have already handled the exception thrown by A's constructor in C's constructor, why should I bother to catch and handle the exception again in the main function?

```
#include <iostream>

class WException : public std::exception
{
public:
    WException( const char* info ) : std::exception(info){}
};

class A
{
public:
    A( int a ) : a(a) 
    {
        std::cout << "A's constructor run." << std::endl;
        throw WException("A constructor throw exception.");
    }

private:
    int a;
};

class B
{
public:
    B( int b ) : b(b) 
    {
        std::cout << "B's constructor body run." << std::endl;
        throw WException("B constructor throw exception");
    }

private:
    int b;
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    C( int a, int b ) try : A(a), B(b)
    {
        std::cout << "C's constructor run." << std::endl;
    }
    catch( const WException& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "In C's constructor" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    try
    {
        C c( 10, 100 );
    }
    catch( const WException& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "In the main: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the exception actually propagate out of `C`'s constructor? If not, why catch it again?

Comment: Who suggested you to catch the exception in `main()` also? Ask him this question!

Comment: @Nawaz, Or her, geez. It's no wonder there are no females in this profession :p

Comment: @chris: Yes, statistically, I'm correct. ;-)

Comment: It seems that for some reason, you assume you *have* to catch it and ask why. To me, no, there is no need to use try/catch in main. But I rarely use exception, I may be wrong.

Comment: @arne it does - the standard demands it.

Comment: For what it's worth, exotic language features like constructor function-try-blocks serve as great ice breakers at parties.

Comment: @Nawaz Come on. An uncaught exception calls abort(). You know it. Why not catch in main()?

Comment: @BЈовић it's about why the exception gets rethrown implicitly - seems he did not know that ;-)

Comment: @ArneMertz: Yes, I didn't know the exception gets rethrown "implicitly". Thanks for teaching me something new today. :) (+1 to your answer)

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, one of those tricky language corners one comes across once in a while - but after reading Sutter's explanation anything else would not make sense ;-)

Comment: @ArneMertz LOL very good! I didn't know it either ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot actually *catch* an exception in a constructor. You can handle it, but you have to rethrow it or another exception. The reason is about object integrity and object lifetimes:

If the construction of `a` throws, a part of `c` has not been initialized and is completely missing - lifetime of `a` never starts. `a` is not an optional part of `C`, otherwise it had to be a pointer or a `std::optional` (since C++14 - `boost::optional` before that).

So how do you assemble a `C` if one of its vital parts cannot be constructed? You can't. `c` can never start to exist as a complete object, so there is no way you can exit the constructor normally. That's the reason why if construction of a member object fails, construction of the whole object has to fail, i.e. *has to* throw an exception.

If you don't throw an exception in `C::C`'s catch block, the compiler will do so for you.

C++ Standard, **§15.3,15**:

> The currently handled exception is rethrown if control reaches the end of a handler of the function-try-block of a constructor or destructor.

For a broader treatment on that topic, see http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm

Comment: Thank all of you, especially @Arne Mertz. And the C++ Standard explains everything, :-)